# Is there any R function or package to count number of columns that two different rows have a same value at the same time and then make diagonal matrix

Tags: r, row, multiple-columns, diagonal

I have two questions. I have a dataset named "dt" looks like this:

```
Name of     general security environment health humanrights tradecommerce finance
organization
IRIN          0        1         1         1        1             0          0 
IWMI          1        0         1         1        0             0          0
Asyl          0        0         0         0        1             0          0
NetHope       0        0         0         1        0             0          0
USC           0        0         1         0        0             0          0
CIFAL         1        0         1         0        1             0          0
```

From here, firstly, I would like to know how many times two different rows have, at the same time, a value with "1" within seven columns. For example, IRIN and IWMI have value with "1" two times together on environment and health above. IWMI and NetHope have the value only once together on health. Actually, there are more dozens of rows. I want to know easy-way to get the numbers in R. Again, I want to know how many times two organizations have same value with "1" within the seven columns.

Second, by having the numbers, and then, I would like to create a diagonal matrix based on the numbers that pair organizations have the value with "1" together.

For example, like this:

```
Name              IRIN IWMI Asyl NetHope USC CIFAL
of organization
IRIN                0    2    1     1     1    2
IWMI                2    0    0     1     1    2
Asyl                1    0    0     0     0    1
NetHope             1    1    0     0     0    1
USC                 1    1    0     0     0    1
CIFAL               2    2    1     1     1    0
```

To describe the matrix, as I explained above, IRIN and IWMI had same value "1" twice within the seven columns. That is why there are X*12* = 2 as well as X*21* = 2 in the 6 * 6 matrix. And, Since IWMI and NetHope have the same value once within the seven columns according to the first dataset above, X*24* = 1 and X*42* =1 as well. So, I want to know how to make this diagonal matrix based on the numbers.

Overall, as I have over 50 organizations, I would like to know, first, R function or code on how to count number of columns that two different rows have a value with "1" at the same time. Second, once I find the numbers, I would like to know how to make the diagonal matrix based on the number of same value "1" among the seven columns between two organizations.

I hope someone understand this complicated question and have solution.

All the best,

Leroy

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you please edit your post to include your data.  The following code will generate a code snippet with 10 random records that you can paste into your original post: dput(dplyr::sample_n(YourDatasetsNameGoesHere, 10)). To use my code, you may need to install dplyr with: install.packages("dplyr")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```r
myfunc <- function(i, j, data, nm = "organization") {
  sum(
    unlist(subset(data, data[[nm]] == i, select = names(data) != nm)) == 1 &
      unlist(subset(data, data[[nm]] == j, select = names(data) != nm)) == 1
  )
}

res <- outer(setNames(nm = unique(dat$organization)),
             setNames(nm = unique(dat$organization)),
             Vectorize(myfunc, vectorize.args = c("i", "j")), data = dat)
diag(res) <- 0 # otherwise, diag(res) is 7, since IRIN==IRIN
res
#         IRIN IWMI Asyl NetHope USC CIFAL
# IRIN       0    2    1       1   1     2
# IWMI       2    0    0       1   1     2
# Asyl       1    0    0       0   0     1
# NetHope    1    1    0       0   0     0
# USC        1    1    0       0   0     1
# CIFAL      2    2    1       0   1     0
```

---

Data:

```r
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
organization  general security environment health humanrights tradecommerce finance
IRIN          0        1         1         1        1             0          0 
IWMI          1        0         1         1        0             0          0
Asyl          0        0         0         0        1             0          0
NetHope       0        0         0         1        0             0          0
USC           0        0         1         0        0             0          0
CIFAL         1        0         1         0        1             0          0 ")
```

Comment: Thank you very much @r2evans . But, as my original dataset is 46 rows and 10 columns, I just replace "dat" on your syntax with the "original dataset" that is csv file. Like this: res <- outer(setNames(nm = unique(original dataset$organization)),
             setNames(nm = unique(original dataset$organization)),
             Vectorize(myfunc, vectorize.args = c("i", "j")), data = original dataset) . But, it turns out  <0 X 0 matrix>. Do you know why?  Is this because that the "dat" is a text-table but my "original dataset" is csv file? Best, Leroy.

Comment: Check your names. I can reproduce that result by using `dat$LSDKJFL` (i.e., random string) instead of `dat$organization`. It seemed unlikely to me that your first column is named `dat$\`Name\nof organization\``, so I just named it `dat$organization`.

Comment: How is it going, Nac-June Choi?

Comment: Oh, it it too late reply, @r2evans. Thank you so much for your comment. I really appreciate it. It worked. My mistake was "organization" that I missed it in the excel sheet, the original csv file. 

Again, I really thank you very much for your help!

Best regards,
Nacjune